# Commuting $\operatorname{Re}$ with integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the following always true?

$$
f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C},\ \operatorname{Re}\left(\int f(z)d z\right) = \int\operatorname{Re}(z)dz
$$
$$
\frac{d\operatorname{Re}(f)}{dz} = \operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{df}{dz}\right)
$$

Is it true for $\operatorname{Im}$?

Comment: $\operatorname{Re}$ and $\operatorname{Im}$ commute with $\int$ by definition of complex integral.

Comment: Note that $dz$ is not a real form. You have $$\operatorname{Re} \int_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz = \int_{\gamma} \operatorname{Re} \bigl( f(z)\,dz\bigr),$$ though. And $\operatorname{Re} f$ is only complex differentiable if it is constant, so $\frac{d\operatorname{Re} f}{dz}$ generally doesn't exist when $\frac{df}{dz}$ exists - only when $f$ is constant, but in that case you have $\frac{d\operatorname{Re} f}{dz} = 0 = \operatorname{Re} \frac{df}{dz}$.

Comment: So if I assume that the differential is real, the statement will always be true?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that:

$$\text{Re}\left(\int_0^i i\;dz\right)=\text{Re}(-1)=-1\neq0=\int_0^i 0\,dz=\int_0^i\text{Re}(i)\,dz$$

Comment: Are there any conditions? Like real interval, infinite interval?

Comment: @Joshhh I'm not sure, but as the commenters say perhaps there's some trivial case when trying to solve a complex line integral